# Overload new and delete inside DLL

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, dll, new-operator

I want to make a simple memory tracker inside a DLL for testing, that apps using the DLL can use.
Since there is no way I know of to overload new/delete inside the DLL in a way that an application using the DLL will also call the overloaded operators inside the DLL, I tried a bunch of things.

**First Question**: Am I correct with above statement, that overloading new/delete operator inside the DLL offers no possibility that the app using my DLL will also call the overloaded new/delete inside the DLL? The app should use it's own global new/delete as far as I know.

My approach was the following:

Inside the DLL:

```
In the header:
__declspec(dllexport) void* operator new(size_t size, const char* file, const size_t line);
void operator delete (void* p);

#define new new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Implementation of new and delete are in the CPP file inside the DLL.

In my app (which uses the DLL) I then include the header from the DLL and when calling `new` in the app, the overloaded new inside my DLL gets called.
When I then call `delete` in my app, the global delete of the app will get called, not the overloaded delete inside my DLL. Of course this is a problem, since calling `new` from a DLL and `delete` from another place on the same "memory object" is undefined behavior.

So what are my options? How can I overload new/delete inside a DLL in a way that Apps using my DLL will also call the overloaded new/delete from my DLL?

Please note: new[] and delete[] should behave the same and are also overloaded by me. I removed them here for simplicity.

Comment: You need to define your scope more clearly.  Does "apps using the DLL" mean only C++?  Only C++ built using a particular compiler version?  Does it include memory allocations inside libraries that the app developers link with, or only the source code compiled with the application and excluding reused third-party libraries?  What about allocations the app makes by calling OS functions (such as `SysAllocString`) and not `new`/`delete` ?

Comment: Yes only C++. It's a DLL written in C++ which should be used in other C++ projects.
Excluding third party libs that are also linked in the app. Only app code itself and code from the DLL that app uses/links to.
If OS functions were included that would be nice, but for now only new/delete. I currently have no idea how to track mem allocs from OS functions which don't use new/delete.

Comment: Also note that it's forbidden to define any keyword as a macro, that includes `new`.  https://eel.is/c++draft/macro.names#2

Comment: A bunch of existing projects have already done this, see for example: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/refs/heads/main/tools/memory_watcher/memory_hook.cc

Comment: Wow MFC uses this too:
```
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#define DEBUG_NEW new(THIS_FILE, __LINE__)
```
If it's forbidden, why does MFC use this?
Also what are the alternatives? Overloading global new/delete inside DLL without macro only works for new/delete calls inside the DLL.

Comment: You also have to be really careful that whatever data you store for memory tracking purposes doesn't allocate using the same instrumented allocator, as that would lead to infinite recursion.

Comment: Yeah MFC does a lot of things which are not allowed by Standard C++.

Comment: The example you posted uses direct hook of Windows Heap stuff if I understand it correctly. Is there no way for new/delete operators?
Yes I know of that recursion problem, that's why I used the macro along with my own new operator instead of overloading the global new op.

Comment: why your exe will be using overloaded new/delete from your dll ? if you write exe by self - you can do this - special use this new/delete. if you not control exe - of course no. that you implement some new/delete in dll have no any effect to exe. in this case - only hooks

Comment: @RbMm: It appears that OP is supplying a header file which will be used while compiling the application.

Comment: @MarcS: If your only reason for using a macro is to prevent the infinite recursion then break the recursion by using OS allocation functions such as `HeapAlloc` inside your `operator new` implementation.  I assumed you were using the macro to capture the file and line information.

Comment: Yes I'm supplying my header file(s) along with the DLL so an EXE can use it. I'm not trying to control an EXE that is not from me and is not built using my DLL.

Comment: @BenVoigt The macro is primarily used so I can use `new` in my App which calls overloaded `new` in my DLL. Since I found no other way of doing that wihtout a macro (or hooks by your example). For file/line info and recursion this is just a nice "side effect" of using this macro.

Comment: @MarcS - you contradict yourself - *EXE that is not from me and is not build ..* - *I'm supplying my header file(s)* - so exe is use your headers during compile process and you lib file during build or no ?

Comment: @RbMm: You read that out of context.  "I'm **not trying to control** an EXE that is not from me and is not built using my DLL."  The application to instrument is one that is built using his header and lib

Comment: @BenVoigt - but not clear for me - are OP compile/build exe by self. if not - any heder files have no any effect for exe

Comment: My EXE/App uses the headers and lib of my DLL for building. I just meant that I don't want to control an EXE that was not build by me and without my headers/lib/DLL(obviously). That was just an answer to "RbMm's" comment "if you not control exe - of course no"

Comment: @MarcS if *My EXE/App uses the headers and lib of my DLL for building* you of course can redirect new/delete for self implementation

Comment: @RbMm Yes well that is the whole question :D How do I do it? I have an EXE that is built with the header/lib of my DLL. Inside the DLL I overloaded new/delete. How can my EXE using the DLL call those overloaded function in the DLL when my EXE calls new/delete?

Comment: but by macro exe (code which use header where macro defined) will be call your implementation of new/delete

Comment: @RbMm Yes that works. But my EXE does not call the overloaded delete inside the DLL. And that's the problem, because this produces undefined behavior. New and delete must always be defined in the same scope. I cannot just simple add a Macro for delete like with new.

Comment: @MarcS: Maybe you should put a very thin definition of your special version of `operator new` directly in the header file, that does nothing more than call your DLL function.  Then you can dllexport a normal function with a normal name, and stop trying to dllexport `operator new()`

Comment: That is: `MEM_TRACKING_DLL void* TrackingNew(size_t size, const char* file, const size_t line); static inline void* operator new(size_t size, const char* file, const size_t line) { return TrackingNew(size, file, line); }`

Comment: Also, **is your header file properly switching between `dllexport` and `dllimport`** depending on whether you are building the DLL or the EXE ?

Comment: of course delete must be match to new. possible redefine and delete too. but anyway will be problems in compile time. for instance some class have self new operator member

Comment: @RbMm: Yes his macro definition will definitely break any usage of placement new, classes with custom operator new, and so on.  This is probably why the Standard forbids `#define new ...`

Comment: This is far more involved than you think it is. Fortunately, the system already provides everything you are trying to re-invent. Debug configurations use the debug heap by default, and the CRT provides functions like [_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtdumpmemoryleaks) that allow you to collect diagnostics. Unless you have a reason to track memory allocations in release configurations as well, that's what you should be using.

Comment: @BenVoigt But with your example, I can no longer use new inside my app and provide tracking. I would need to write an overload for new inside the app too, that would then call my DLL function. Yes header switches between import/export. Just wrote the declspec directly in the question.

Comment: @IInspectable Tracking should be available in Release, otherwise I would have used the CRT debug stuff.

Comment: So to summarize: There is no way to overload new+delete inside a DLL so that my App will also call those overloads in the DLL without using my macro or writing another new+delete overload in my App which then call the DLL functions?

Comment: "I would need to write an overload for new inside the app too, that would then call my DLL function."  Well yes, but the header file takes care of this detail so there's no extra work to do in the app.

Comment: @BenVoigt But how should I implement this for delete? I cannot write a macro for delete inside my header DLL, and without the macro the overloaded delete will not be called from my App. Or am I getting things wrong here?

Comment: This is probably all operating on the wrong level. You should go at least one step deeper, and override `malloc`, `free`, and friends. See how [mimalloc](https://github.com/microsoft/mimalloc) does it if you need inspiration.

Comment: @MarcS: It's not the macro, it's the `static inline` global definition that calls to the DLL "normal" function.  You do replacement of global `operator delete` in the usual way inside the app.  But it doesn't have any implementation details, it simply calls your `TrackingDelete` that's exported from the DLL.

Comment: @IInspectable: Or one level higher and do `std::allocator` and `std::make_unique`, so you can capture type information.

Comment: @BenVoigt Okay now I get what you meant. Yes that would be a solution, but my requirements were, that I don't have to write an overload for new/delete inside the app, which then call my DLL functions.
Just include the header in the App and link against my shared lib and the app should use the new/delete from the DLL.

Comment: @MarcS: If you write it inside the header file, it is inside the app, but doesn't require any work from the app developer.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think I'm misunderstanding you. Here is my complete file structure: pastebin.com/MLAvyw73     I get this error when building my app: `C2323: 'operator new': non-member operator new or delete functions may not be declared static or in a namespace other than the global namespace` Looks like compiler doesn't support `static` on `new` anymore.

Comment: @BenVoigt Also I just realized I must have a solution without any macros, because a macro for delete would break the `delete` keyword on class constructors.

Comment: @MarcS: Ok, just remove the `static` keyword.  `inline` by itself will have the required behavior for a function defined in a header file.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes thath works. But it needs to have the macro. Is there a solution without any macros? Like I wrote above, I cannot create a macro for delete, this will brake stuff in my code.

Comment: I don't understand why you think you need a macro.  What's wrong with putting `MEM_TRACKING_DLL void TrackingDelete(void*); inline void operator delete(void* p) { return TrackingDelete(p); }` in your header file?